# Same file different MD5 checksum in C#

Tags: c#, file, md5, checksum

Here is the scenario. I have a winforms application which has an auto-update feature. This application contains a method which calculates the md5 checksum of the current (local) exe file and compares it with the md5 checksum of the (server) exe file to determine if there is any new updates on the server by comparing the hashes of the 2 files on local machine and the server.

Now this method works perfectly on some PCs that I have and when I run the application it gives same checksum hashes. The problem is on some other PCs I always get the auto-update message because I'm getting different MD5 hashes, Now after that the application starts the auto-update and re-downloads the file on my server, I get a new exe file with a totally different hashes. I'm really confused what is possibly can cause this? is it a problem from the C# downloading method? is it a problem from the md5 function it self? any inputs would be appreciated...

EDIT: a method to calculate md5 checksum

```
public static string GetMD5HashFromFile(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var buffer = md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(buffer[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It may help to include your method for calculating the MD5 hash - it *might* be locale dependent, for instance...

Comment: How about simply reading the file (or assembly) version of the executable and sending this to the server for comparison?

Comment: If you have the original executable and an executable the problem occurs at, you could simply do a byte-by-byte comparison of both to determine if the problem is MD5 calculation or the executable actually being different.

Comment: @UweKeim - I know that but I'm also using this method to make sure that the version on the local pc is identical to the one on the server. its a security measure

Comment: @RobinVanPersi I understand. (I would simply check for the _exact_ file size, but your requirements may be higher). You could also do Authenticode signing and check whether the signature is valid, I guess...

Comment: @Jon - there is nothing special about the code that I have.. I've updated the question...

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - how to do that? can you show an example?

Comment: @UweKeim - that would be way more complicated I guess...

Comment: There is the risk that those computers infected with some malware that will infect your executable.

Comment: @RobinVanPersi you can copy paste Microsoft's example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320348 - or even download a 3rd party md5 tool to compare them. You'll only need to check this once to determine what the problem is in your case.

Comment: @RobinVanPersi your MD5 code looks fine to me, so the files are actually different _or_ the `filename` you pass to the method does not point to the correct file _or_ I'm wrong :) Also the download has finished (disposed of any stream used during download etc) before you compute the checksum, right?

Comment: Have you ran a virus/rootkit check on the target machine to ensure that nothing is infecting the file with malware enroute?

Comment: Probably the encoding of file on the second server is different

Comment: @Theraot - nope those PCs are clean.. I also thought about that but this is not the case...

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - no its correct otherwise I'd see an error or it will throw an exception. the file is being downloaded using the simple webclient class and yes its getting disposed.

Comment: @RowlandShaw - the machine is clean and I've just installed a new fresh windows on it..

Comment: @MohsenAfshin - can you be more specific? what do you mean?

Comment: For example you can paste 2 equal text into 2 different file and save them with different encoding (e.g, ANSI vs UTF-8). Be sure the encodings are equal

Comment: its not a text file. its an exe and both are the same file

Comment: Hi, not solved yet? It seems to be that I had my preconscious mind working on this, because sudently I though that maybe your problem was the endianess of the manchines affecting the calculation of the hash. Does those machines happen to have the same CPU? Also try moving the file from one of the machines with the problem to one that doesn't have it and let it do the ahs there to see if it passes.

Comment: nope. now I believe its a problem from the internet connection. because I'm downloading the file from my server. so I zipped the file and re-downloaded it again and unzipped it now I'm having the same hashes on my server. so I believe its a problem from the internet connection.

Comment: You probably should compare raw bytes of the files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes), which can answer why hashes differ. Downloaded binaries can be modified by many things which change the raw bytes and the hash in turn, so it might not easy to track down. Zipping seems to be the right way, as there are some extra validation.